# Bingo, the story of my dog

Tags: meaning

BINGO

```
 "Ye Franckelyn's dogge leaped over a style,
 And yey yclept him lyttel Bingo,
  B-I-N-G-O,

 And yey yclept him lyttel Bingo.
 Ye Franchelyn's wyfe brewed nutte-brown ayle,

 And he yclept ytte rare-goode Stingo,
  S-T-I-N-G-O,

 And he yclept ytte rare goode Stingo.
 Now ys not this a prettye rhyme,
 I thynke ytte ys bye Jingo,
  J-I-N-G-O,

 I thynke ytte ys bye Jingo."
```

It's kind of rhyme from Ernest Thompson Seton's "Wild Animal I have known" (1898)

Can somebody decipher it into modern English?
Just literally, aside from its meaning.

Comment: You know there's a modern version, too, yeah? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bingo_(folk_song). Just FYI :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Middle English where

["Yclept"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clepe) is past participle of the archaic verb "clepe" meaning to name/call.

[Stingo](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stingo) is strong ale or beer.

Franckelyn seems to be a variant of Franklin (name). As a noun [franklin](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/franklin) means a medieval English landowner of free but not noble birth.

[Jingo](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jingo) might be used as a mild oath usually in the phrase *by jingo*.

“Bingo” is also a 17th century slang term for brandy (as in “stingo and bingo,” strong ale and brandy)". [The source](http://www.word-detective.com/2008/02/bingo/).

With all this in mind, translating the rest of the rhyme into your mother tongue becomes much easier or it can just be guessing.

Answer (score 1):

The freeman's dog jumped over a style (gate)

And they called him little Bingo

B. I N G O

And they called him little Bingo

The freeman's wife brewed nut-brown ale

And he called it exceptionally good Stingo
S T I N G O

Now, isn't this a pretty rhyme?

I think it is, by Jingo (Jesus)

J I N G O
I think it is, by Jingo.

Comment: Why Franckelyn in your translation is a postman, not a farmer, or a landlord?;-)

Comment: @Rompey Franckelyn is an old word for what we now call a postman. Hence the term franking for stamping or adding postage to an envelope.

Comment: I saw other versions. Suggesting to agree to disagree)

Comment: You're right, I'll edit.